# iOS Replaykit Screen Recording with Custom Video Setting (resolution, bitrate etc.)

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I'm using Replaykit framework to capture screen in iOS 14 app, xcode 12. I need to provide custom setting (screen resolution, bitrate etc) to store the recorded video. is there way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to provide any settings for the ScreenCapturing.
You should work with those data returned by the system. It's not difficult:

- for video processing, you may use CAImage or Metal
- for audio proccessing - AVAudioPCMBuffer and AVAudioConverter